# How to configure MySQL in Fluent nHibernate c#

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string

I am switching connection from Ms. SQL server to MySQL.
Now I am facing problem in connection for Fluent nHibernate.
This is my code:

```
var strDbConnString = "server=localhost;user id=root;password=root;database=testing_v60;";

   ISessionFactory _sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure()
                                       .Database(MySQLConfiguration.Standard
                                       .ConnectionString(strDbConnString)
                                       .Driver<NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver>().ShowSql())
                                       .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<AspnetSession>())
                                       .BuildSessionFactory();
```

I also add this line in web.config:

```
<entityFramework codeConfigurationType="MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlEFConfiguration, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6">
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="v11.0" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6" />
  <!--<provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />-->
</providers>
```

After I debug, I got this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection' to type 'System.Data.Common.DbConnection'.

Am I missing something in web.config?

Thanks a lot!